# Why is my scanner reading numbers in a text file as a string?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, fileinputstream

I have a text file that has grocery items followed by the isle they are on in a text file. For some reason, my scanner is only picking up on the data as a string and not a string and an int. Below is my code that is super simplified to try and troubleshoot:

```
public static void readItems(String filename){
    String groceryItem;
    int groceryIsle;
    String specialArea;
    try{
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
        Scanner s = new Scanner(fis);
        while (s.hasNext()){
            **System.out.println(s.next());**
        }
    } catch(IOException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(GroceryPlanner.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println("Can not open the file!");
    }
}
```

This just prints out all of the names of the items and the isle number. When I change the highlighted line of the code to `s.nextInt()`, I get

> Exception in thread "main" `java.util.InputMismatchException`

Here is a link to snippet of the input file

[image]

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a snippet of the input file as well.

Comment: When you use `nextInt()` you try to read `int` values from the input file. However, your input file also contains text.

Comment: @Progman, does s.next() generally grab integers? I thought that it only grabbed Strings

Comment: @TaylorBancroft `next()` will return the text between the delimiter of the `Scanner` object, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--

Comment: @Progman, thank you so much! Sometimes it is just a matter of knowing how to formulate the question when you are doing your own research.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably assuming `nextInt` grabs the next int, but that's not the case: it [scans the next token of the input as int](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()). If it finds a String instead, an `InputMismatchException` is thrown.

Since your input starts with a String, this exact exception is thrown.

Comment: Thank you! I get it now!